# Java constructor is undefined in UserInterface class

Tags: java

The rest of the code is fine, for some reason I am getting an error in the `UserInterface` class. I am new at java so I do apologize in advance if it's a simple error that can be fixed in a few seconds and I am asking this question. I am using java Eclipse Oxygen. Please if you can provide your answer and also an explanation on how you did it, so I can also learn in the process instead of just having the solution.

The error is:
The constructor `Bbat(String, String, int, Store, String, String, int)` is undefined - UserInterface.java

Here is the code for the Bbat class and User Interface class.

```
package stage02;

public class Bbat extends SportsGoods {

    private boolean fullTime;
    private String studentType;
    private double currentFees;


    public Bbat () {
        super (null,null,0,null);
        fullTime = true;
        studentType = null;
        currentFees = 0.0;
    }
    public Bbat (String gN, String fN, int age, Store ei, boolean fT, String sT, double cF) {
        super (gN, fN, age, ei);
        fullTime = fT;
        studentType = sT;
        currentFees = cF;
    }

    public boolean getFullTime() {
        return fullTime;
    }
    public String getStudentType() {
        return studentType;
    }
    public double getCurrentFees() {
        return currentFees;
    }
    public void setFullTime (boolean fT) {
        fullTime = fT;
    }
    public void setStudentType (String sT) {
        studentType = sT;
    }
    public void setCurrentFees (double cF) {
        currentFees = cF;
    }

    public String toString () {
        return super.toString() + "\nFull Time: " + (getFullTime()?"Yes":"No") +
                    "\nStudent Type: " + getStudentType() +
                    "\nCurrent Fees: $" + getCurrentFees() + " per hour\n";
    }
}
```

User Interface:

```
package stage02;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class UserInterface {

 public void begin() {

  ArrayList < SportsGoods > people = new ArrayList < SportsGoods > ();

  boolean finished = false;
  while (!finished) {
   int selection = showMenu();
   switch (selection) {
    case 1:
     people.add(addCbat());
     break;
    case 2:
     people.add(addBbat());
     break;
    case 3:
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Displaying the stock information ...", "Stock List", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
     for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, people.get(i), "Product Information", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
     }
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + people.size() + " record(s) in the list", "Total records", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
     break;
    case 4:
     finished = true;
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "*** Program Ended ***\n" +
      "*** Thank you for using this program ***");
     break;
    default:
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n** Invalid Selection **\n", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   }
  }
 }

 public int showMenu() {
  int selection = 0;
  String stringSelection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
   "******* MENU *******\n\n" +
   "1. Add a new Cricket Bat\n" +
   "2. Add a new BaseBall Bat\n" +
   "3. Display all Details\n" +
   "4. Exit Program\n\n" +
   "Type the number of your selection, and click OK: ");
  selection = Integer.parseInt(stringSelection.trim());
  return selection;
 }

 public Cbat addCbat() {
      String aName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\nWhat is the Bat's model? ").trim();
      String bName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is " + aName + "'s grip? ").trim();
      int age = 0;
      do {
       String stringValidAge = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is " + aName + "'s price? (no decimal places) ");
       double doubleAge = Double.parseDouble(stringValidAge);
       age = (int) doubleAge;
       if (age <= 1 && age > 200) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error - cost must be greater than 1 to be sold by this store", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       }
      } while (age <= 1 && age > 200);

      String eType = null;
      do {
       eType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is " + bName + "'s colour? ".trim());
       if (!eType.equals("Red") && !eType.equals("Blue") && !eType.equals("Yellow") && !eType.equals("Black") && !eType.equals("Green")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n** Invalid Selection **\nBat grip colour must be Red, Blue, Yellow, Black, or Green",
         "ERROR",
         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       }
      } while (!eType.equals("Red") && !eType.equals("Blue") && !eType.equals("Yellow") && !eType.equals("Black") && !eType.equalsIgnoreCase("Green"));

      String eNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is " + aName + "'s Product Code? ");
      double nYE;
      do {
       String stringNYE = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many " + aName + " are in stock?");
       nYE = (int) Double.parseDouble(stringNYE);
       if (nYE < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n** Value must be zero or more **\n", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       }
      } while (nYE < 0);
      String or = null;
      or = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Name of store involved ? ");
      String city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "City where " + or + " is ? ");
      Store org = new Store(or, city);
      Cbat s = new Cbat(aName, bName, age, org, eType, eNum, (int) nYE);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you - bat added to the list", "Bat added", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
  return s;
 }

 public Bbat addBbat() {
  String gName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\nWhat is the Bat's model? ").trim();
  String fName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is " + gName + "'s grip? ").trim();
  int age = 0;
  do {
   String stringValidAge = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is " + gName + "'s price? (no decimal places) ");
   double doubleAge = Double.parseDouble(stringValidAge);
   age = (int) doubleAge;
   if (age <= 1 && age > 200) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error - cost must be greater than 1 to be sold by this store", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   }
  } while (age <= 1 && age > 200);

  String eType = null;
  do {
   eType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is " + fName + "'s colour? ".trim());
   if (!eType.equals("Red") && !eType.equals("Blue") && !eType.equals("Yellow") && !eType.equals("Black") && !eType.equals("Green")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n** Invalid Selection **\nBat grip colour must be Red, Blue, Yellow, Black, or Green",
     "ERROR",
     JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   }
  } while (!eType.equals("Red") && !eType.equals("Blue") && !eType.equals("Yellow") && !eType.equals("Black") && !eType.equalsIgnoreCase("Green"));

  String eNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is " + gName + "'s Product Code? ");
  double nYE;
  do {
   String stringNYE = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many " + gName + " are in stock?");
   nYE = (int) Double.parseDouble(stringNYE);
   if (nYE < 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n** Value must be zero or more **\n", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   }
  } while (nYE < 0);
  String or = null;
  or = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Name of store involved ? ");
  String city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "City where " + or + " is ? ");
  Store org = new Store(or, city);
  Bbat e = new Bbat(gName, fName, age, org, eType, eNum, (int) nYE);
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you - bat added to the list", "Bat added", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
  return e;

 }
}
```

Your help to this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling wrong constructor `Bbat e = new Bbat(gName, fName, age, org, eType, eNum, (int) nYE);` which is not defined i.e. parameter types does not match.

so, your constructor should have below definition:

```
public Bbat (String gN, String fN, int age, Store ei, String fT, String sT, double cF)
```

Also `fullTime` is of type boolean. But you are passing `String` as parameter so either make `fullTime` as `String` or pass boolean in place of `eType` from where you are calling (`Bbat e = new Bbat(gName, fName, age, org, eType, eNum, (int) nYE);`)

Comment: I have that constructor in my Bbat class, so what do I need to do to define it with the user interface? I am guessing maybe the code in the user interface is wrong?

Comment: First decide which parameters do you need in Bbat constructor and write your code accordingly. Read the message. I've explained.

Comment: So what you are saying whatever I have in the Bbat constructor section, I need to have the exact same in the User Interface and in the same order as well?

Comment: Correct, from wherever you are calling this constructor from

Comment: I matched up them up in the Bbat and User Interface in the same way and I am still getting the error, the person above said that the eType should not be a Boolean and that it needs to be changed to fixed the problem. So where would I need to go in the code to fix that?

Comment: if your constructor is like below:
`Bbat(String, String, int, Store, String, String, double)`
you need to call it like this `new Bbat("abc", "abc", 8, new Store(or, city), "abc", "abc", 8)`

and if your constructor is like below:
`Bbat(String, String, int, Store, boolean, String, double)`
you need to call it like this `new Bbat("abc", "abc", 8, new Store(or, city), false, "abc", 8)`

Hope it clears your doubt